# How to use REST API with FaunaDB?

Tags: graphql, serverless, graphql-js, faunadb, jamstack

I have created a collection in my Fauna database. I also made an index that returns all the data in that collection. I want to know if there is a way to get JSON REST API to work with this data. What I mean by this is I want a URL that I can 'GET' using XMLHttpRequest and then parse into JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You might say that Fauna is "HTTP native".  All of the language drivers (JS, C#, Python, etc.) are built on top of http requests. That is, there are no special connections or connection-pools to maintain. You can get pretty far with using the JS driver in the browser, for example, without using a server.

But to answer your question more directly, there are many ways to serve a REST API, and it is going to depend on how you want to serve the API.

### Examples

#### AWS

Here is a blog post on how to set up a REST API with AWS App Runner, for example.

https://fauna.com/blog/deploying-a-rest-api-with-aws-app-runner-and-fauna

#### Vercel and Netlify

There are also some example apps on github that demonstrate using a REST API with

Vercel:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-cookie-auth-fauna

Or Netlify:
https://github.com/netlify/netlify-faunadb-example

Both of which host serverless functions for you to create a REST API.